# Django Manytomanyfield returns the same project many times

Tags: python, django

On my Django site, I have two models - one is Project, which a user can create, and one is Access, where a user can add other users for access to the project. The Access model contains a manytomanyfield where the additional users are stored. I can add users and remove users from this field and it works site-wide (ie if I add a user onto the project, then log into that user's account, I can see it) but if I add more than one collaborator, I will start to see multiple iterations of that project in my project stream. It seems to me that Django is showing me the project for each user in the access_list as opposed to just once.

Models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
project_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
project_thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
project_pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.project_name

def save(self):
    if not self.id and not self.project_description:
            return

    super(Project, self).save()
    Access.objects.get_or_create(project=self)
    if self.project_thumbnail:
            size = 200, 200
            image = Image.open(self.project_thumbnail)
            image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            fh = storage.open(self.project_thumbnail.name, "w")
            format = 'png'  # You need to set the correct image format here
            image.save(fh, format)
            fh.close()

def get_project_thumbnail(self):
    thumb = str(self.project_thumbnail)
    if not settings.DEBUG:
            thumb = thumb.replace('assets/', '')

    return thumb

class Access(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    access_list = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required 
def projects(request):
    thisuser = request.user

    if Access.objects.filter(Q(access_list=thisuser) | Q(project__created_by=thisuser)).exists():
        projects_by_username = Access.objects.filter(Q(access_list=thisuser) | Q(project__created_by=thisuser)).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')
    else:
        projects_by_username = None

    return render_to_response('projects.html',
                                {'projects_by_username': projects_by_username,
                                'user': thisuser })
```

projects.html:

```
{% for project in projects_by_username %}

<table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="3"><a href="/projects/get/{{ project.project.id }}">
{% if project.project.project_thumbnail %}
    <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{project.project.project_thumbnail}}" width="150" /></td>
{% endif %}
    </a></td>
    <td width="75%" valign="top"><div class="heading16px"><a href="/projects/get/{{ project.project.id }}">{{ project.project.project_name }}</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/projects/get/{{ project.project.id }}">{{ project.project.project_description }}</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out some code? If you have a call to the super's save method at the top level of your class definition, that is almost certainly going to cause you problems, if it even works in the first place. The `get_or_create` call below that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: There's other stuff underneath the super about resizing the image and saving it as a thumbnail under PIL so I didn't include that. I can include the Project model's entire save function if you like